# QGIS Georeferencing - removing co-ord bubbles from .tiff file layer

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm new to QGIS ...

I've georeferenced a raster image using the georeferencing tool. That went well. However, when the new TIFF layer opened, it still had the yellow co-ord bubbles. How do I remove these as I can create a map and they are not a good look?

Comment: Do you have a *.points file in the same folder and with the same name as the raster file? If yes, if you move it to a backup folder or rename it, and load the layer again, the issue is solved?

Comment: Oops ... I've solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

They are the Ground Control Points that can be saved by the [Georeferencer Plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html#georeferencer-plugin), for later use if you want to adjust them, in a **.points* file in the same folder and with the same name as the raster file.

You can export the raster layer to a new file, or copy the raster and move the points to a backup folder to avoid that issue.